# While importing auto_arima from pmdarima: ERROR : cannot import name 'factorial' from 'scipy.misc'

Tags: python, scipy, python-3.7, factorial

I have python 3.7.1 and scipy version : 1.3.0. I'm getting error while calling auto_arima saying : "cannot import name 'factorial' from 'scipy.misc'"

Just this basic import causes the issue:-
    "from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima"
I've tried reinstalling scipy, didn't work

Comment: Can you add the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) to the question?  There is useful information in there, and it would help track down which module is trying to import `scipy.misc.factorial`.

Comment: Regressing scipy v1.3.0 seems to work: python3.6 -m pip install scipy==1.2

Answer (score 4):

The function `factorial` was moved from `scipy.misc` to `scipy.special`.  The version in `scipy.misc` has been deprecated for a while, and it was removed in scipy 1.3.0.  Something in pmdarima or one of its dependencies is still using the name `scipy.misc.factorial`.

The culprit appears to be statsmodels 0.9.0.  pmdarima depends on statsmodels, and there is code in statsmodels 0.9.0 that imports `scipy.misc.factorial`.  <strike>The development version of statsmodels has a fix for that, but 0.9.0 is the latest release.</strike>  The problem should be fixed if you upgrade `statsmodels` to version 0.10 or later.

The statsmodels developers are aware of the issue; see

- https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5620
- https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5747