# How to fix this error while using statsmodels" ImportError: cannot import name 'factorial'"?

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, arima

I have already gone through this answer
[While importing auto_arima from pmdarima: ERROR : cannot import name 'factorial' from 'scipy.misc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206632/while-importing-auto-arima-from-pmdarima-error-cannot-import-name-factorial) 
but couldn't fix the error,I do not understand how to use developer version.
Is there any other method for applying Seasonal ARIMA model?

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train_weekly.Price,
                                order=(1, 0, 0),
                                seasonal_order=(1, 1, 0, 12),
                                enforce_stationarity=False,
                                enforce_invertibility=False)

results = mod.fit()
print(results.summary().tables[0])
print(results.summary().tables[1])
```

Following is the output

```py
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-a5d9120bdc57> in <module>()
----> 1 import statsmodels.api as sm
      2 mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train_weekly.Price,
      3                                 order=(1, 0, 0),
      4                                 seasonal_order=(1, 1, 0, 12),
      5                                 enforce_stationarity=False,

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/statsmodels/api.py in <module>()
     14 from . import robust
     15 from .robust.robust_linear_model import RLM
---> 16 from .discrete.discrete_model import (Poisson, Logit, Probit,
     17                                       MNLogit, NegativeBinomial,
     18                                       GeneralizedPoisson,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py in <module>()
     43 
     44 from statsmodels.base.l1_slsqp import fit_l1_slsqp
---> 45 from statsmodels.distributions import genpoisson_p
     46 
     47 try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/statsmodels/distributions/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from .empirical_distribution import ECDF, monotone_fn_inverter, StepFunction
----> 2 from .edgeworth import ExpandedNormal
      3 from .discrete import genpoisson_p, zipoisson, zigenpoisson, zinegbin

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/statsmodels/distributions/edgeworth.py in <module>()
      5 import numpy as np
      6 from numpy.polynomial.hermite_e import HermiteE
----> 7 from scipy.misc import factorial
      8 from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
      9 import scipy.special as special

ImportError: cannot import name 'factorial'
```

I just want to use seasonal ARIMA,if there is any other way please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: [This issue is solved temporarily](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5759#issuecomment-494086228).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like there is a version mismatch of [scipy](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#history) module. Try downgrading scipy module.

In windows execute the following command in Administrative mode,

```
pip3 install --user scipy==1.2.0
```

If you're using Linux,

```
python3.6 -m pip install scipy==1.2 --upgrade
```